# gfortran -fbounds-check doesn't always work?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I have noticed a case where gfortran's bounds checking doesn't trap a bug.  I have included a minimal working example here:

```
program bounds2d                                                                                                                                             

  implicit none 
  integer arr(3,3) 
  integer i 
  integer csum 

  arr = 2 

  write(*,*) 'arr' 
  do i=1,3 
    write(*,*) arr(i,:) 
  end do 

  write(*,*) 'column sums' 
  do i=0,3                     ! <-- 0 is out of bounds here
    call mysum(arr(:,i), csum) 
    write(*,*) csum
  end do 

contains 

  subroutine mysum(x, xsum) 

    integer, intent(in) :: x(:) 
    integer, intent(out) :: xsum 
    integer i 

    xsum = 0 
    do i=1,size(x) 
      xsum = xsum + x(i) 
    end do 

  end subroutine mysum 

end program bounds2d
```

After compiling with `gfortran -o bounds2d.x -g -fbounds-check bounds2d.f90`, I get the following output:

```
$ ./bounds2d.x
 arr
           2           2           2
           2           2           2
           2           2           2
 column sums
  -586968606
           6
           6
           6
```

Interestingly, if I use the sum intrinsic in the do loop instead of my own subroutine, gfortran does catch the error at runtime:

```
  do i=0,3                     ! <-- 0 is out of bounds here
    write(*,*) sum(arr(:,i))
  end do
```

Output:

```
$ ./bounds2d.x
 arr
           2           2           2
           2           2           2
           2           2           2
 column sums
At line 19 of file bounds2d.f90
Fortran runtime error: Array reference out of bounds for array 'arr', lower bound of dimension 2 exceeded(0 < 1)
```

**Is this behavior a bug or a feature?**  The latest version of gfortran I have tested this on is 4.8.1.  Also, due to restrictions outside of my control, I am required to adhere to the Fortran 95 standard or earlier (no F2003/F2008 extensions).

Comment: It's a bug. Please file a report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: It also isn't caught by a few versions of Intel's compiler (`16.0.3.210` and `13.2.146`) at least. Note that using the address sanitizer under gfortran catches the error. Compile with `gfortran -f sanitize=address -g prog.f90`

Comment: @RussF, thanks.  I wasn't aware of the address sanitizer.  I did run the code under valgrind, which does catch the error (and I think does something similar to the address sanitizer?).